# Вся графика игры в одном файле

Tags: unity3d, спрайт

Я пишу игру на юнити 2д. Когда я смотрел видео одного чувака, он запихнул ВСЕ спрайты в один пнг файл, минимального формата, для экономии веса. Я так и не понял, каким образом это сделать, чтобы потом это было реально использовать в юнити

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала вам необходимо создать текстуру, где будут храниться спрайты. С помощью любого удобного вам редактора разместите в свободные места спрайты. Перенесите полученную текстуру в папку **Assets**. Далее выберите текстуру и установите **Texture Type** на **Spreite(2D and UI)**, а **Sprite Mode** на **Multiple**, и примените изменения. Далее нажмите на **Sprite Editor**. В появившемся окне слева сверху нажмите на выпадающее меню **Slice**, выберите нужный вам тип разделения, а потом нажмите **Slice**. Вокруг каждого спрайта должна появиться едва заметная рамка. Далее нажмите **Apply** в окне сверху справа. Результат должен быть таким:

[image: Разделенные текстуры]